# Как получить ответ от запроса из RTK на прямую в редьюсер

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Так вот у меня такая проблема, я не хочу получать данные от запроса **RTK** в компоненте через хука **useEffect()** а потом уже диспачить в редюсер, как вызвать хуки от **RTK** сразу в **редьюсере** или в **экстраредьюсере** и добавить ответ сразу в **стейт** или может не через **хуки** я не знаю, просто не хочу что бы в **компонентах** писалась такая логика. Буду благодарен за помощь.